# MATLAB - 'webread' slow because of content-type checking?

Tags: matlab, performance, http, download

I use *webread()* to download data from a website's API.

Everything works - except that each function call is way too slow for my needs.

According to the profiler a large portion of the processing time is spent in a function called *HTTPConnector.getConnectionContentType()*.

[image]

But it doesn't even seem to matter whether or not I'm using *weboptions()* for specifying the content type **explicitly** -

*HTTPConnector.getConnectionContentType()* seems to get called by *webread()* no matter what.

Here's a code snippet to show which options I've specified for the call to *webread()*:

```
url = %someURL
options = weboptions('MediaType',    'application/json', ...
                     'ContentType',  'json'            , ...
                     'KeyName',      'Authorization'   , ...
                     'KeyValue',    ['Bearer ', api.token]);
response = webread(url, options);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Or Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: Faced the same problem and technical support told me that it was not possible to increase the speed of the function. Ended up using a third party tool to download/save.

Comment: @marsei  What third party tool did you end up using? Urlread2?

Comment: Outside Matlab (didn't find any trick for speedy downloads within Matlab). I tried in order of increasing speed calling chromium, programming multithread C++ and using MacOS Automator in conjunction with a SSD hard drive. But that's purely personal and I am far from being an expert.

Comment: @marsei: I guess the primary advantage was the use of multiple parallel connections?

Comment: @Daniel yes. with Matlab you are stuck with one connection. The only thing I was able to do is to download multiple files at a time - but was interested in downloading single-based big files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the type is not what slows down your code. The `getConnectionContentType` function is the first function which requires the content of the response and thus triggers the download of the data. If you would bypass it, the next function which looks into the content would show up in your profile.

For reference, open the HTTPConnector.m and read the comment for getConnectionContentType